# Javascript FileReader.onload not working after a form submit (POST)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, filereader

At the moment I am creating a single page uploader. I develop in Javascript (+jQuery) and I use [AppJS](http://appjs.org/).

This uploader has 2 forms where upload inputs are available. Both forms in 1 page and the second form is hidden `display: none;`

Both use the same custom made upload extension.

- In the first form I ask for 2 images, they have to be dropped.
- When I drop the image, it is uploaded to my nodejs server via sockets and saved correctly.
- When I drop the second one, again, it is uploaded to my nodejs server and saved correctly.
- Then I post the form to my nodejs server
- After that I `.hide()` the first form and `.show()` the second one.

When I use the upload plugin again, no error appears but also no file is uploaded.

I noticed that the FileReader.onload is not executed after the first form is posted.

Below some sample code, I cannot post my whole application.

### HTML

```
<form id="formone" action="/formone">
    <input type="text" name="background" value="Drop here" class="uploadinput" readonly />
    <input type="text" name="logo" value="Drop here" class="uploadinput" readonly />
</form>
<form id="formtwo" action="/formtwo" style="display:none;">
    <input type="text" name="icon" value="Drop here" class="uploadinput" readonly />
</form>
```

### Javascript

```
// File upload extension
$.fn.extend({
    filedrop: function() {
        return this.each(function() {
            var files = []
            var $this = $(this)

            // Catch drop event
            $this.bind('drop', function(event) {
                event.stopPropagation()
                event.preventDefault()

                console.log('Dropped') // Works in both forms

                files = event.originalEvent.target.files || event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files

                file = files[0]

                var reader = new FileReader()

                // reader.onload only works in form 1
                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    var buffer = e.target.result
                    socket.emit('uploadfile', file.name, buffer)
                }

                reader.onerror = function(error) {
                    console.log("error", error)
                    console.log(error.getMessage())
                }

                reader.readAsBinaryString(file)

                return false
            })
        })
    }
})

$('.uploadinput').filedrop()

window.showFormTwo = function() {
    $('#formone').hide()
    $('#formtwo').show()
}
```

### Node.js

```
app.router.post('/formone', function() {
    window.showFormTwo()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The function filedrop is called as soon as the javascript loads, but your form2 is hidden then. From [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) API :

> Handlers are attached to the currently selected elements in the jQuery
>   object, so those elements must exist at the point the call to .bind()
>   occurs. For more flexible event binding, see the discussion of event
>   delegation in .on() or .delegate().

So because form2 is hidden drop event is never bound, and its event handler is never called. reader.onload is inside this event handler. `.on` is the preferred way of attaching event handler function to elements.

So change this

```
$this.bind('drop', function(event) {
```

to

```
$this.on('drop', function(event) {
```

Comment: That doesn't work, the `$this.bind('drop', function(event) {` is executed in the second form. When I `console.log()` in the drop event it works. Only the onload doesn't. If I display both forms, my uploader also works. So you are right somewhere.